# How is a war file created for spring boot with maven?

Tags: maven, spring-boot

I'm trying to follow the guide for converting a spring project to a war.

http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

It starts out using maven and gradle and then right after the jar portion it completely forgets about maven and only has gradle updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main changes that you need to make in the pom. The first is to change the project's packaging type to `war`:

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-convert-jar-to-war</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

The second is to add a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` and mark it as provided:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

`mvn package` will now produce a war file that can be run using `java -jar` or deployed to a separate servlet container.

Answer (score 3):

There is an official guide at spring:
http://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war-maven/

Pay attention to "Initialize the servlet" section.

It explains an important point of adding a class that substitutes web.xml. Without it (or without proper web.xml) you will get a war file but when deployed nothing will be accessible in browser as nothing will be registered as your request dispatcher.

Also note that it is best to run this example on Tomcat 8 as it supports latest servlet specs. I have spent number of hours trying to figure out why it does not work on my Tomcat 7.

Comment: This answer contains crucial info re: getting a war file that does nothing. Thank you.